# Clearing tmux terminal throws error: "'tmux-256color': unknown terminal type."

Tags: terminal, tmux, colors, xterm

Originally, I was trying to determine why some directories show up differently colored than others when using the `ls` command.

While playing around with this. I have now encountered the problem of not being able to clear the screen inside a tmux terminal

```
$ clear
'tmux-256color': unknown terminal type.
```

This problem only persists in tmux, not the actual terminal itself and only showed up after trying to fix the initial problem. Also the colors have changed when running vim inside tmux now.

Here are some outputs:

**outside tmux**:

```
$ echo $TERM; tput colors; tput longname
xterm-256color
256
xterm with 256 colors
```

**inside tmux**:

```
echo $TERM; tput colors; tput longname
tmux-256color
tput: unknown terminal "tmux-256color"
tput: unknown terminal "tmux-256color"
```

**EDIT:**

my .bashrc file has:

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

my .tmux.conf has:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: You haven't told the world whether the `tmux` terminal type is missing, too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your plaform doesn't have `tmux-256color`, you will need to either:

1) Use `screen-256color` instead.

2) See if you can upgrade ncurses or terminfo to a later version with `tmux-256color`.

3) Copy `tmux-256color` from another computer which does have it, you can do this by saving it with `infocmp -x tmux-256color >saved` then installing it with `tic -x saved`.

Comment: How do I persistently change it to your first point? I think i've done it before with `export $TERM=screen-256color` but after closing the terminal and restarting, the same error occured.

Comment: The better approach is to leave it at the _right_ terminal type, as it currently is, and use M. Marriott's second or third options.

Comment: Yeah, that's worked for me. point 3 is persistence. @DouglasJamesBock please vote this answer as solution.

Comment: Regarding the `export` command of @DouglasJamesBock : there's no $-sign while setting variables; the $ is only used to show the content, e.g. `echo $TERM`

Answer (score 9):

An approach that has always worked for me in this situation (when ssh'ing onto a foreign VM etc) is simply typing

```
export TERM=xterm
```

You can also add this as a `.profile` entry on the foreign box too if permission allows to make it permanent.

Answer (score -2):

By default `tmux` used `TERM=screen256` on Ubuntu for color display. However I could not display icon etc. in `tmux`.

By using `export LANG=en_IN.utf-8` it solved the problem. Another approach I used to display correctly was by using `tmux -u`.